# How-to debug vanilla Java app built with Maven in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a vanilla java application. It imports a couple of external libraries. I'm using Maven to retrieve these dependencies, and to perform the compile, test, etc.

Now, I would like to debug my app in IntelliJ.

Option 1: Debug it as "Application" - but then I miss the jars that Maven retrieves automatically.

Option 2 : Debug it as "Maven" - apparently the debugger starts but it get stuck after displaying

> [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli)

Either way seems extremely complicated for launching "just a debugger" for a simple app that just uses one external library. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

On the right, open the Maven tab. Then click on the "Reload All Maven Projects" button at the top left of that dock. It should align the dependencies of your modules in Intellij with those in the maven pom(s).

When you create an IntelliJ run configuration, make sure you select the correct IntelliJ module.